# Linking 2 cpp files

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzfYR.png)

I am supposed to call the function randint to my main function but for some reason it doesn't work. I have 3 files: randint.cpp, randint.h, and main.cpp. And I am supposed to call the function from randint.cpp. I am not sure if I am supposed to just declare the function in the header file and and write the definition in the cpp file.

> main.cpp

```
#include "std_lab_facilities_5.h"
#include "randint.cpp"
#include "randint.h"
int main()
try {

    int x = randint();
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}


catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " <<e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n";
        return 2;
    }
```

> randint.cpp

```
#include "randint.h"
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

//linear congruential pseudorandom number generator

int randint() {
    //use the clock for an initial pseudorandom number
    static long x = time_point_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();
    //calculate the next pseudorandom number
    // parameters from glibc(?)
    x = (((1103515245L * int (x)) & 0x7fffffff) + 12345)& 0x7fffffff;
    return x;
}
```

> randint.h

```
int randint();
```

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question.

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant. Never include code as pictures (accessibility problems) or on an external site (the site may go down), instead copy the code into the question and format it as a code block. Questions doing the above are off-topic.

Comment: Do *not* include a cpp file in another cpp file

Comment: The compiler is correct about the warning. Although in this case you probably want to use a cast.

Comment: Include only the .h file not the .cpp file. Even if you put the definition in .cpp file (which you better should do) you only include the header file.

Comment: Unrelated, but the reason the code doesn't work might be something else: you should put everything after `int main()` inside `{  }`.

Comment: For some reason you have `#include "randint.cpp"` in main.cpp. Don't do that.

Comment: It was the randint.cpp that was inside main. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

In the .H file inside the class you want

```
public:
int randint();
```

and in the .CPP that you want to call the function you need:

```
        randint randint; //<--- Telling the class in this case main that randint exists(second randint can be whatever name you prefer)

       randint.randint(); //<--- Here you call the function
```

I would also recommend you to use the class wizard when creating new files.

Comment: You don't have to make everything a class.